# AWS Serverless contact form request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops

I have a static website (a simple landing page) hosted on AWS S3, with Cloudfront enabled in front of it.

I would like to add a public contact form request.

I found some solutions but I would like to know which one is the best.

1/ Front-end JS send a message to an SNS topic and subscribe my email to it (but it means that I need to share an AccessKey in public)

2/ Front-end JS send a message to SNS, trigger a Lambda function which process and send email via SES.

3/ Front-end JS send a POST request to a public API Gateway, trigger a Lambda function which process and send email via SES

4/ Others?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: #3 is the only one that doesn't require AWS SDK (and your Access Keys) in the client-side JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd option is the best and easiest one to implement. Also as @Mark said in comments, you don't need to keep your access keys in client side in this case.

Answer (score 1):

3rd for sure. You could even use API Gateway's AWS Service Proxy and call SNS/SES API directly, without the need of using AWS Lambda.

[This tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) covers this use case.